# Symfony2 new bundle

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I recently started my journey to Symfony2 world. The archive I downloaded (Standard edition) comes with a demo bundle the AcmeDemoBundle.  I tried to code along with the Symfony2 book provided by the official site. So I created a bundle of my own(EXPHelloBundle) through  the Symfony2 console. Then, I created the controller associated with the current bundle.

The problem is this: Whenever I run my app (localhost/app_dev.php/hello/whatever) browser prints "hello whatever". I know that this message runs from the AcmeDemoBundle (the bundle that comes with Symfony2 archive). Whatever changes I make to my EXP/HelloController.php, the app naturally runs the AcmeDemoBundle (as a default).
To put it simply, I don't know how to tell Symfony2 to run my bundle instead of the demo bundle.

Comment: The @Route("/new/hello/{name}", name="new_demo_hello") part is very important, these anotations is what Symfony uses to match the routes with the functions. Take a look at the Routing documentation on the Symfony site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to route the HTTP requests to your new controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newHelloAction($name)
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

This code in `src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php` tells Symfony to execute the helloAction function whenever a /hello/whatever is received.

Try writing the following function i your new controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new/hello/{name}", name="new_demo_hello")
 * @Template()
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

And go to /new/hello/something in your browser

The key is the routing component, take a look at it in the cookbook and you will see it's pretty easy one you get the basic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this to remove the acme bundle correctly:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html